# Are there other examples of applications of a priority arbiter apart from sharing system bus or memory?

Tags: fpga, embedded, hdl

I was wondering where else a priority arbiter is used in the real world, apart from sharing a system bus or memory. I tried googling, but couldn't find any other examples.

For context: I'm working on a mini project which requires us to implement a priority arbiter on an FPGA (this FPGA also comes with a hard processor  a SOC).

I've completed this part, but now the following question is to suggest one application using the output from the arbiter and implement it. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding questions that ask for examples (i.e. opinions): *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.* <-- there is no right or wrong answer and, even if there were a clearly very popular answer given and accepted, within a month, or a year, that answer could be out of date (and wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to consider what resource with fast access may multiple bus masters want to access simultaneously and often.

A microcontroller with multiple CPU cores, or with one CPU and a Direct Memory Access Controller (DMAC), can contain multiple internal shared resources: memory (Flash EPROM, SRAM) and peripherals (timers, UARTs, general-purpose I/O (GPIO)). These will need arbitration, either across a shared bus or at an individual device level. The latter is commonly used, to increase transfer speed and bus master efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TonyM. Would it make sense if I implement 2 write modules and 1 read module trying to access a single memory location and have the arbiter control the data flow?

Comment: @Ash, you're very welcome but that comment really is an opinion-based question which I can't answer. That part's up to you.